# Malformed Entry 1 in list file error for kubuntu Xenial

Tags: apt, package-management, kubuntu

Upon executing `sudo apt-get update`, I get the following error:

```
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-stable.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I have tried to rewrite this file, but it states that I lack write access. Please help.
Also, I think that this may also be the reason that the Discover GUI for Ubuntu app store is not running at all as well.

Upon opening the file:

```
deb http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable xenial
main

main
main
```

Can anyone please suggest what is wrong with the above text? I am unable to perform `sudo apt-get update`...

Comment: @user5937 Are the `main` entries in the file on separate lines just like you pasted it? It should be the last argument on the line with URL.

Answer (score 2):

Open that file as root with a text editor, like Gedit:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-stable.list
```

Remove everything from the file and paste only this:

```
deb http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable xenial main
```

Save the file and "sudo apt-get update" should work.